# express server app.use(express.static(x)) - can't access my endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, server, static, client

I do not understand how the express.static works, therefore I can't have access to my index.html on the views file.

The express.static code is on the app.js file.

I just need to know how can I display my html file on the views repertory.

Please find below a copy of my screen and thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: Please replace a screenshot of code with an actual code wrapped by a code block using backticks.

Comment: This is not a code question. I'm fine with my code. I'm just asking regarding the directory on the left how can I access the index.html file on the views repertory as end point.